# Maximum Gcd and Sum

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x, greatest-common-divisor

> You are given two arrays *A* and *B* containing *n* elements each. Choose a pair of elements (*x*, *y*) such that:
>   • *x* belongs to Array *A*
>   • *y* belongs to Array *B*
>   • GCD(*x*, *y*) is the maximum of all pairs (*x*, *y*).
>   If there is more than one such pair having maximum gcd, then choose the one with maximum sum. Print the sum of elements of this maximum-sum pair.

This is question from Hackerrank [weekofcode](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/w34/challenges/maximum-gcd-and-sum) 34.

```
from fractions import gcd

from itertools import product
n = int(input().strip()) #two arrays of equal length
A = set(map(int, input().strip().split(' '))) #array1
B = set(map(int, input().strip().split(' '))) # arry2
output_sum=[]
output_GCD=[]
c=list(product(A,B))
for i in c:

    temp1=i[0]
    temp2=i[1]

    sum_two=temp1+temp2

    temp3=gcd(temp1,temp2)
    output_GCD.append(temp3)
    output_sum.append(temp1+temp2)
temp=[]
for i in range(len(output_GCD)):
  if(output_GCD[i]==max(output_GCD)):
    temp.append(output_sum[i])
print(max(temp))
```

This solution works for smaller conditions and I got timed out for most of the test cases, please help me how to improve my solution.

Comment: Not sure if this is faster, but instead of computing the GCD for each pair (O(n²)), maybe just compute all the divisors for all the numbers in A, store them in a map `{divisor -> [numbers]}`, then for all the numbers in B, again compute all the divisors and get the largest that's already in the map.

Comment: You could drop non-maximal elements with respect to division within each array to reduce the number of comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate all divisors `a_divisors` for array `A` by next way:

```
# it is not real python-code, just ideas of algorithm
count = {}
for (i : A): 
  count[i]++

a_divisors = {}
for (i : range(1, 10^6)):
  for (j = i * i; j <= 10^6; j += i):
    if j in count.keys():
      a_divisors[i] = 1
```

After you can construct same array `b_divisors` for `B` and after choose common maximum from both arrays

For example:

```
5
3 1 4 2 8
5 2 12 8 3
```

produce arrays of divisors:

```
a: 1, 2, 3, 4, 8
b: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 12
```

Common maximum is: 4

If you know `gcd(a, b) = 4` than you just choose 1 maximal value from `A` that has divisor `4` and 1 from `B`: 8 + 12 = 16

Comment: Second part seems okay, but I'm sure there are more efficient ways to determine all divisors than to test all the numbers up to some arbitrary upper bound.

Comment: There is no any division and sum/multiplication is really fast, but Key-Map is not fast. 

Firstly, I think that is really better to replace Key-Map to array with mask length of 10^6, it is significant improvement of speed.

And second idea is going to `sqrt(10^6) = 10^3` in first range-loop, and add both `a_divisor[j / i ]` and `a_divisor[i]`

Comment: There is no division, but there are still _very_ many tests. What if the largest number in one of the arrays is 10^100? Would you still use 10^6 as upper bound? Or test all the numbers up to 10^100?

Comment: tobias_k, it is guaranted that every `A[i]` and `B[i]` not great than 10^6

Answer (score 0):

You must convert A and B to Set(to easily find in it)

```
def maximumGcdAndSum(A, B):
    A = set(A)
    B = set(B)
    max_nbr = max(max(A), max(B))
    i = max_nbr

    while i > 0:  # for each i starting from max number
        i_pow = i  # i, i^2, i^3, i^4, ...
        maxa = maxb = 0

        while i_pow <= max_nbr:  # '<=' is a must here
            if i_pow in A:
                maxa = i_pow  # get the max from power list which devides A
            if i_pow in B:
                maxb = i_pow  # get the max from power list which devides B
            i_pow += i
        if maxa and maxb:
            return maxa + maxb  # if both found, stop algorithm
        i -= 1

    return 0
```